# GTK warning when running python

Tags: gtk

When running a python program in the alacritty terminal, I get the following warning:

`Gtk-WARNING **: 16:48:40.877: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:6321:10: 'height' is not a valid property name`

I have had a look in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` and this is what I get.

```
[Settings]
gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme=0
gtk-button-images=1
gtk-cursor-theme-name=Pop
gtk-decoration-layout=icon:minimize,maximize,close
gtk-enable-animations=1
gtk-font-name=Noto Sans,  10
gtk-icon-theme-name=candy-icons
gtk-menu-images=1
gtk-primary-button-warps-slider=0
gtk-theme-name=Sweet-mars
gtk-toolbar-style=GTK_TOOLBAR_BOTH_HORIZ
```

The `gtk.css` file just has `import 'colors.css';`. I can't find a 'height' parameter, so I'm not sure how to resolve the warning. However, I notice that some of the parameters in `settings.ini` are not up-to-date (e.g. I'm currently using 'sweet-dark' theme, not 'sweet-mars').

Comment: Do you use a custom theme?

Comment: For the terminal? Yes, I use gruvbox for the alacritty terminal. If it is that causing the problem, is there any way to suppress the warning?

Comment: My guess would be that the custom theme contains a CSS "height" property, which is not supported by GTK. I'd try to find that and remove it (and file a bug for the theme developer if this is the case)